# How to display image from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display an image coming from the database and I was not able to display the image .but its showing like this `user-1.jpg` Please see my code can one guide me how to display the image.

```
$sqlimage = "SELECT image FROM userdetail where `id` = $id1";
$imageresult1 = mysql_query($sqlimage);

while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($imageresult1))
{       
    $image = $rows['image'];    
    print $image;
}
```

Comment: Tip: please dont use mysql_* functions because they are deprecated. You can use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Use [Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid those annoying SQL injections. Your question is not clear if you have an image in your database or only a file name.

Comment: @markust i my databse its showing user-1.jpg,can you tell me how to save the image inside the databse

Comment: @Xavi So your database stores only the file name. This is one valid method for storing files. You got answers already. Storing an image in the database is a different question. Use google if you're interested in answers.

Answer (score 21):

> Displaying an image from MySql Db.

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DbName"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
```

Answer (score 4):

For example if you use this code , you can load image from db (mysql) and display it in php5  ;)

```
<?php
   $con =mysql_connect("localhost", "root" , "");
   $sdb= mysql_select_db("my_database",$con);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE 1";
   $mq = mysql_query($sql) or die ("not working query");
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($mq) or die("line 44 not working");
   $s=$row['photo'];
   echo $row['photo'];

   echo '<img src="'.$s.'" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px">';
   ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
       $connection =mysql_connect("localhost", "root" , "");
       $sqlimage = "SELECT * FROM userdetail where `id` = '".$id1."'";
      $imageresult1 = mysql_query($sqlimage,$connection);

      while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($imageresult1))
    {       
       echo'<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$rows['image'].'">';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

put you `$image` in `img` tag of html

try this

```
echo '<img src="your_path_to_image/'.$image.'" />';
```

instead of

```
print $image;
```

your_path_to_image would be absolute path of your image folder like eg: `/home/son/public_html/images/` or as your folder structure on server.

**Update 2 :**

if your image is resides in the same folder where this page file is exists
you can user this

```
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this to display image

```
$sqlimage  = "SELECT image FROM userdetail where `id` = $id1";
$imageresult1 = mysql_query($sqlimage);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($imageresult1))
{
    $image = $rows['image'];
    echo "<img src='$image' >";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

You need to use html img tag.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace

```
print $image;
```

with

```
 echo '<img src=".$image." >';
```

Comment: Why you use <?php inside an echo?

Comment: ans has been Updated !

Comment: Great. Now it may help question's owner

Comment: Never ever render a filename this way, consider putting it between quotes (double quotes this time). Although specifications allows for missing quotes, one will get in trouble if misses closed tags and his filename contains "/
"

Answer (score 0):

instead of `print $image;` you should go for `print "<img src=<?$image;?>>"`

and note that $image should contain the path of your image.

So,
If you are only storing the name of your image in database then instead of that you have to store the full path of your image in the database like /root/user/Documents/image.jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlimage  = "SELECT image FROM userdetail where `id` = $id1";
    $imageresult1 = mysqli_query($link, $sqlimage);

    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($imageresult1))
{

    echo "<img src = 'Image/".$row['image'].'" />';


}
```

Comment: You should usually include an explanation in your answer, not just code. It otherwise may not always going to be clear why it works (or if it works). Also, code-only answers without explanations often get downvoted and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect ("localhost:3306","root","");
    $db = mysql_select_db ("database_name", $conn);

    if(!$db) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

    $q = "SELECT image FROM table_name where id=4";
    $r = mysql_query ("$q",$conn);
    if($r) {
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
            header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");       
    echo $row ["image"];
        }
    }else{
        echo mysql_error();
    }
    ?>

sometimes problem may  occures because of port number of mysql server is incoreect to avoid it just write port number with host name like this "localhost:3306" 
in case if you have installed two mysql servers on same system then write port according to that

in order to display any data from database please make sure following steps
1.proper connection with sql
2.select database
3.write query 
4.write correct table name inside the query
5.and last is traverse through data
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

put this code to your php page.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM userdetail";
$result = mysqli_query("connection ", $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    echo "<img src='images/".$row['image']."'>";
    echo "<p>".$row['text']. "</p>";
}
```

i hope this is work.