# How to upload an image in PHP?

Tags: php

I try to upload image but it unsuccessful! All information will insert into database except image. I try use text and blob type for image before also not success. I only can use mysql because all of my coding using mysql to insert into database and not mysqli.

Below is my register code

```
<?php
//register
error_reporting(0);
include 'connect.php';
$submit = $_POST['register'];
//form data
$fullname = strip_tags($_POST['fullname']);
$username = strtolower(strip_tags($_POST['uname']));
$password = strip_tags($_POST['pass']);
$repeatpassword = strip_tags($_POST['r_pass']);
$useremail = strip_tags($_POST['useremail']);
$gender = strip_tags($_POST['gender']);
$date = date("Y-m-d");

if(isset($submit))
{
if ($fullname&&$username&&$password&&$repeatpassword&&$useremail&&$gender)
{
//open database
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("phpforum"); //select database  

$namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);
//check username in database
if($count >0)
{
$unameErr =  "*Username already taken!";
}else{
//check letter username
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z _]*$/",$username)) {
$unamelErr = "* Only letters and white space allowed"; 
}else{
//check match password and repeat password
if($password==$repeatpassword)
{
//check char length of username 
    if (strlen ($username)>20||strlen($username)< 3 || strlen ($fullname)>20||strlen($fullname)<3)
    {
     $lengthErr ="* Must Between 3 and 20 characters!";
    }else{
            //check password length
            if (strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6)
            {
                $lengthpErr = "* Must Between 6 and 25 characters!";
            } 
            else
            {
            if(!move_uploaded_file(($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"images/".$_FILES['image']['name']))){
                echo "Image upload fail!";
            }else{
            //register user
            $password = md5($password);
            $repeatpassword = md5($repeatpassword);

            $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id,name,username,password,email,date,level,image,gender)VALUES ('','$fullname','$username','$password','$useremail','$date','$level','".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"','$gender')");

            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"; 
            echo "alert('You have been registered!');";
            echo "window.location='forum.php'";
            echo "</script>";
            }
            }
        }

}
else 
    $passErr = "* Your password do not match!"; 
    }
}
}
else
$fillErr = "* Please fill in all fields!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Instead of saving your image in a database, just save it as a file somewhere.

Comment: how can i save , im new in php

Comment: You could use the easy `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_file)` (Use this only for uploaded files, otherwise learn about the filesystem of `PHP`)

Comment: Please read about SQL injection, strip_tags is not enough to prevent your db from being dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to save images into database. Upload the images to the directory you wish and just save the path in database.

```
 $destination = 'YourdesireDestination/';
$fileName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
 move_uploaded_file($fileName, $destination);
```

And the save the path to database.

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id,name,username,password,email,date,level,image,gender)VALUES ('','$fullname','$username','$password','$useremail','$date','$level','".$destination.$fileName "','$gender')");
```

Or if you want  to save image to db then

Try this

```
   $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
```

and then

```
 $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id,name,username,password,email,date,level,image,gender)VALUES ('','$fullname','$username','$password','$useremail','$date','$level','$image','$gender')");
```

Comment: database image type use text or blob?

Comment: @ahkeat that should be blob

Comment: create a column with datatype var char and just save the image path to database that would be easy to use and when you will SELECT query to database then the desire image path would be attached and then echo the IMAGE PATH  in the src Attr of IMG tag

Comment: i think my problem is cannot use $_FILES because when i use $_POST['image'], it will insert into db

Comment: @ahkeat Do you get anything in $_FILES?? If not then check your form enctype attr if it is not set then try enctype="Multipart/form-data"

Comment: how can i display the image inside the files?

Comment: @ahkeat Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842268/how-to-display-image-from-database-using-php