# Why are my images echoed in these weird characters?

Tags: php, html, sql, image, phpmyadmin

I inserted an image into my phpmyadmin database using this:

```
UPDATE
inventory
SET
IMG = LOAD_FILE('A:/Programs/XAMPP/htdocs/SamsCarLot/images/mercedes-benz.jpg')
WHERE
VIN = 'WDDGF8AB9DR298549';
```

When I try to echo it onto my webpage I get these very odd looking characters
[click to view photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVI59.jpg)

My syntax is correct I'm sure, correct me if it isn't, but I don't know why my image is converting itself from my database to these funky characters.

```
<?php
$vin = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['VIN']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE VIN = '$vin'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Model FROM inventory WHERE VIN = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $vin);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($model);
$stmt->fetch();
echo "<h1>$model</h1>";


// Loop through all the rows returned by the query, creating a table row for each
while ($result_ar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $img = $result_ar['IMG'];
  $year = $result_ar['YEAR'];
  $make = $result_ar['Make'];
  $model = $result_ar['Model'];
  $trim = $result_ar['TRIM'];
  $color = $result_ar['EXT_COLOR'];
  $interior = $result_ar['INT_COLOR'];
  $mileage = $result_ar['MILEAGE'];
  $transmission = $result_ar['TRANSMISSION'];
  $price = $result_ar['ASKING_PRICE'];
}
echo "<IMG src='$img' width='250'>";
echo "$year $make $model</p>";
echo "<p>Asking Price: $price </p>";
echo "<p>Exeterior Color: $color</p>";
echo "<p>Interior Color: $interior </p>";

$conn->close();
//INSERT INTO images (img) VALUES ('A:/Programs/XAMPP/htdocs/Sam'sCarLot/images/ferrari.jpg')
?>
```

Comment: Are you storing images as a blob in the database?

Comment: `LOAD_FILE` reads a file and returns the content as a string - so what you are seeing is basically correct. It is however better to store just the path to the image rather than a blob like this

Comment: Yes as a LONGBLOB

Comment: UPDATE
inventory
SET
IMG = LOAD_FILE('A:/Programs/XAMPP/htdocs/SamsCarLot/images/mercedes-benz.jpg')
WHERE
VIN = 'WDDGF8AB9DR298549'; is the only way I know how to store an image in a database. I'm new to this, I've never used a sql script to store an image before and when I googled how to do it that's the code I got

Answer (score 0):

To display the image if stored as a blob

```
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, " . base64_decode( $img ) . "' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the image as binary data in your database (`blob` column). When you display your image, you are putting that binary data into the `src` attribute of your `img`-tag.

You need to provide a link to the image (e.g. a seperate PHP file, that queries the image from database and outputs it to the browser) or use proper encoding of the data.

Example with extra php file:

```
$vin = $_GET['vin']; 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Model FROM inventory WHERE VIN = :vin");
$stmt->bind_param(":vin", $vin);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

// Output image
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); // For jpg-files
echo $row[0];
```

Example with encoding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27696825/1392490