# How to display a field of type BLOB from mySQL on html page

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I've tried several times but I have not found a solution, I need to display an image that was saved as BLOB in the database.

Part of the code that saves to the database and displays the data

```
function manage_report($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '')
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('doctor_login') != 1)
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?login', 'refresh');

    if ($param1 == 'create') {

        $data['img_principal'] = $this->input->post('img_principal');

        $this->db->insert('report', $data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('report_created'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?doctor/manage_report', 'refresh');
    }
    if ($param1 == 'edit' && $param2 == 'do_update') {

        $data['img_principal'] = $this->input->post('img_principal');

        $this->db->where('report_id', $param3);
        $this->db->update('report', $data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('account_updated'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?doctor/manage_report', 'refresh');

    } else if ($param1 == 'edit') {
        $page_data['edit_profile'] = $this->db->get_where('report', array(
            'report_id' => $param2
        ))->result_array();
    } 

    $page_data['page_name']  = 'manage_report';
    $page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('manage_report');
    $page_data['reports']    = $this->db->get('report')->result_array();
    $this->load->view('index', $page_data);
}
```

As I'm trying to show on the .html page

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['img_principal']; ?>"/>
```

database

```
CREATE TABLE `report` ( `report_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `img_principal` blo NOT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display image from database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842268/how-to-display-image-from-database-using-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve images from MySQL database and display in an html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793009/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-in-an-html-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You need a script which will serve those blobs, call it `img.php` for instance. One need to pass some kind of ID so it can locate the row in the database as well.

The script can be invoked in HTML:

```
<img src="/img.php?image_id=1" alt="Database image no. 1">
```

This script should:

1. Connect to the database
2. Locate the data using the `(int) $_GET['image_id']` input in this case
3. Send the `Content-Type: image/jpeg` header (or appropriate)
4. Send the `Content-Length` header ([strlen](http://php.net/strlen) of the blob)
5. Send the `Content-Disposition: inline` header
6. Echo the blob

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(  $row['img_principal'];).'"/>';
```