# PHP loop values into javascript array

Tags: javascript, php

Hello I built a manual slider using jquery, and I put my images' location inside an array, but now I want to load images from the database, and I want to loop them to a javascript array. How can this accomplished?

```html
<?php
$get = $connect->query("SELECT imagem FROM slider ORDER by id");

while($fetch = $get->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

}
?>

<script>
    var items = ["url(images/banner_1.jpg)","blue","black","green"];
</script>
```

Comment: The images themselves are in the database?

Comment: yes i post them trough my backoffice

Comment: You are going to probably want to make an endpoint to retrieve the images individually.

Comment: Could you post some code so i can actually understand what u mean, i mean logically i cannot see how this can be done

Comment: You will have to do some research but here is a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46390496/3623866

Comment: Would  it work like this for example , a php while loop moving the image to a variable and then pushing it with js to the array?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple/low-frills method. It doesn't have any external dependencies as you mentioned.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Use PHP in JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>

  <?php
    // assuming your database call returns a valid array like this
    $things = array("banner_1.jpg", "banner_2.jpg", "banner_3.jpg", "banner_4.jpg");
    // the built-in `json_encode` will make JavaScript like it
    $things_json = json_encode($things);
  ?>

  <div class="etc">
    <!--this is were the database items will go-->
    <ul id="things"></ul>
  </div>

  <script>
    // echo out json-ified PHP directly into the script tag
    var things = <?php echo $things_json ?>;
    // loop through the json and append list items to our target element
    for(var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
        document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += '<li>'  + things[i] + '</li>';
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The main tricks here are:

1. use `json_encode($your_array_here)`, which is built in to php
2. `echo` the json directly into a script tag in the body.

You can even work with the new `things` variable from an external script assuming you keep it in the [global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) and have your external js run on [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or similar.

Here are some images of the code working:

[image: code in vim and php server running]
[image: list items populated in the chrome browser]

Note that [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will only accept one variable at a time. If you need to pass multiple variables down into the script, you can build up an array (map) in php with [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), or just `json_encode()` each variable separately and make multiple echo calls inside the script tag.

```
<?php
    // assuming your database call returns a valid array like this
    $things = array("banner_1.jpg", "banner_2.jpg", "banner_3.jpg", "banner_4.jpg");
    $more_things = array("banner_5.jpg", "banner_6.jpg");
    $both_things = array_merge($things, $more_things);
    $both_things_json = json_encode($both_things);
  ?>


  <script>
    // echo out json-ified PHP directly into the script tag
    var bothThings = <?php echo $both_things_json ?>;
  </script>
```

Comment: There is only one problem with this, when passing for example a directory "test/test/image.jpg"  when passing it trough json it returns like this "test\/test\/image.jpg"   how can i fix this ?

Comment: I fixed with preg_  , but how can i pass 2 variables trough json encode , as if if pass 2 json encodes, only the first one shows data

Comment: I added more info about handling multiple PHP variables to the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

**A much simpler method,** without adding things in the DOM, and since you asked for a javascript array:

You have to always remember that PHP executes first in server and javascript later in the browser. So you can use your php to create (valid) javascript, like this:

```
<?php
echo '<script>var jsArray = [];';

while($fetch = $get->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ // I took your line exactly as you wrote it
    echo 'jsArray.push("'. $fetch['field']  .'");'; //you change 'field' with whatever you need
}

echo '</script>';
?>
```

The output of php script (the code that will be executed by javascript) will be something like this:

```
<script>
    var jsArray = [];
    jsArray.push("blue");
    jsArray.push("red");
    jsArray.push("yellow");
</script>
```

After that, you will be able to access jsArray.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, was what i was thinking but needed a valid example to do it correctly, thanks !

Comment: ;) I'm glad to help! If you think so, vote it as best answer

Comment: I used your example as it was simpler, i cannot vote because i don+t have enought reputation :(