# Inserting and Displaying image from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display an image which have been stored in MySQL, but haven't been able to get a success just yet. Apparently echoing the table header (img) gives me back something like this

[image]

In addition I would like to be able to add the image in the website itself rather than using the phpmyadmin and inserting the image there.

As of now this is the code I have for the `standing.php` page

```
<?php
    require_once('database.php');

    // Get all categories
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM categories
              ORDER BY categoryID';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $teams = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-- the head section -->
<head>
    <title>NBA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico"/>

</head>

<!-- the body section -->

<body>
    <main id="standingListMain">

    <h1 id="addCategoryh1">Team Standings</h1>
    <table id="standingListTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($teams as $team) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $team['categoryID']; ?></td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $team['categoryName']; ?>
              <?php echo $team['img']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <br>

    </main>
    <!-- <footer id="standingListFooter">
        <p>&copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> NBA</p>
    </footer> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, the user can add or remove a team from the `team_list.php` page and view it on the standings page

```
<?php
    require_once('../Model/database.php');

    // Get all categories
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM categories
              ORDER BY categoryID';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $teams = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-- the head section -->
<head>
    <title>NBA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico"/>

</head>

<!-- the body section -->

<body>
    <main>
    <h1 id="addCategoryh1">Teams</h1>
    <table id="categoryListTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($teams as $team) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $team['categoryName']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <form action="delete_team.php" method="post"
                      id="delete_product_form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="team_id"
                           value="<?php echo $team['categoryID']; ?>">
                    <input id="deleteCategoryList" type="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <br>

    <h2 id="add_category_h2">Add Team</h2>
    <form action="add_team.php" method="post"
          id="add_category_form">

        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="input" name="name">
        <input id="add_category_button" type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
    <br>
    <p><a href="../index.php">View Team List</a></p>

    </main>
    <footer id="categoryListFooter">
        <p>&copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?> NBA</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Code above is the `team_list.php` page and below is the code to connect to the database called the `add_team.php`

```
<?php
// Get the team data
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');

// Validate inputs
if ($name == null) {
    $error = "Invalid team data. Check all fields and try again.";
    include('../Error/error.php');
} else {
    require_once('../Model/database.php');

    // Add the product to the database
    $query = 'INSERT INTO categories (categoryName)
              VALUES (:team_name)';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':team_name', $name);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();

    // Display the team List page
    include('team_list.php');
}
?>
```

[image]

The image above shows the page where u can add or remove a team.

Comment: You have to put an image into an HTML `<img....>` tag if you want the browser to display it properly

Comment: ALso `phpMyAdmin` is not storing this, MYSQL is. `phpMyAdmin` is a tool written in PHP that makes maintaining a MYSQL database a little easier

Comment: How can i accomplish that If u don't me asking

Comment: So in the `standing.php` page is where i put the image tags right?

Comment: Yes, instead of putting it in a `<td>` you do `<td> <img .......></td>` for example

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35056782/2310830

Comment: Ahh got it :D. One more question, is there a way on how I can insert the image in the `team_list.php` page instead of going to phpmyadmin to insert it?

Comment: Not sure I understand that question :)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I added an image to show you the `team_list.php` page where u can add or remove a team. Back to the question I had, I wanted to be able to add the image there, so like when I add a new team there is also an option to add an image to it as well.

Answer (score 0):

**For testing purposes**

First you need to know if the Image really exist. Let's assume that in your database you have an image with category Id of 1. Thus create another file, eg "image.php".

(Please ensure that this code runs correctly. I have not tested it but it should work for you).

**image.php**

```
<?php 

 require_once('database.php');

    // Get all categories
    $query = "SELECT img FROM categories where categoryID=1";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $num = $statement->rowCount();
 
if( $num ){

    $teams = $statement->fetchAll();
   
    // Ensure to specify header with content type,
    // you can do header("Content-type: image/jpg"); for jpg,
    // header("Content-type: image/gif"); for gif, etc.

    header("Content-type: image/png");
    
    //display the image file
    print $teams['img'];
    exit;
}else{
 //echo no image found with that Category Id.
   
}

?>
```

Then in your "standing.php", remove this code:

```
  <?php echo $team['img']; ?>
```

and replace it with:

<!– "1" is the categoryID id of the image to be displayed –>

```
<img src="image.php?id=1" />
```

Comment: So what I did was I replaced                                                                                 `<?php echo $team['img']; ?>`                                                                             with                                                                                                                       `<?php echo '<img id="teamImage" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $team['img'] ).'"/>'; ?>`            and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Thats okay. Its just that your question was confusing. I taught that your image was saved as blob in the database. Anyway good luck my dear....