# got stuck with displaying images

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, php-7

I am trying to display an image from the database, however, the image does not appear, but instead, an image icon appears, see image

[this is the image icon with 2 warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clfhn.png)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
    $usertable = "table1";
        $db  = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb') or die("unable to dbect");

        $sql = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT image1 FROM table1 WHERE id = '1'");
        $sth = $db->query($sql);
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_decode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
}
```

if anyone could fix the code,
thank you very much

Comment: Are you sure you want base64_encode() instead of base64_decode()?

Comment: Also, are you sure that your connection is `$db` and not `$database`?

Comment: Third, are you sure that you select `image1` field but output `image`?

Comment: you are mixing procedural mysql and object oriented mysql

Comment: @u_mulder made the changes and it didn't work either

Comment: @Ash-b ?? yes, but how do i fix it

Comment: What changes did you make? [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

actually it suppose to be Base 64

for that you have given `echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64` so you should not encrypt or decrypt  it .

**more**
[How to display image from database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842268/how-to-display-image-from-database-using-php)

> Try

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$result['image'] .'"/>';
```